# SharePoint order list item not a created date but order by Ascending

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have follwoing CAML query:

```
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='Glossary' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
```

But the output is odering the list on created date. How can print the list item based on custom column?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the OrderBy in the right place. Your CAML query should look like this :

```
<listName>Program Roadmap: Tracking Development Hours</listName>
<viewName></viewName>
<query>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
      <FieldRef Name="Date" Ascending="true"></FieldRef>
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
</query>
<viewFields>
  <ViewFields Properties="True">
    <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef>
  </ViewFields>
</viewFields>
<rowLimit>0</rowLimit>
<queryOptions>
  <QueryOptions>
    <DateInUtc>False</DateInUtc>
    <Paging ListItemCollectionPositionNext=""></Paging>
    <IncludeAttachmentUrls>True</IncludeAttachmentUrls>
    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>False</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
    <ExpandUserField>False</ExpandUserField>
    <ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive"></ViewAttributes>
  </QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
```